# Return error from spring controller via ajax call

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to develop a spring boot application involving sports, I can not see how to return my error after an ajax call in the error section instead of success, I wonder how I can recuperate all the returns coming from the controller of the Class error in the error section and not in the success section

**N.B : Everything work fine in this code, only errors are returned in success part.**

**Class Error:**

```
public class Error extends Exception{    
    public String code;    
    public String message;
}
```

**Class Sport:**

```
public class Sport {

    public String id;

    public String name;
}
```

**Ajax Call**

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "/sports-actions",
    data: {"id" : sportId},
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function (result) {       
           console.log(result);                
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})
```

**Spring Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sports-actions")
public class SportController {  

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object deleteSport(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
        return new Error(404, "id is not valid");
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I extended my Error class from Exception, but I have error doing this

`throw new Error(400 ,"id is not valid")` // I get incompatibale type...

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do following for testing purpose:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteSport(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
    if({if id exists}) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>({your response object}, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        //If the id doesn't exist.
        return new ResponseEntity<Error>(new Error(),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

**Best Practice**

You should use `@ControllerAdvice` to handle exceptions using `@ExceptionHandler` on method level.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestControllerAdvice {
    @ExeptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Error> handleNotFound(NotFoundException nfe) {
        //LOG error
        Error error = new Error();
        error.setCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        error.setMessage("ID not found OR Your custom message or e.getMessage()");
        return new ResponseEntity<Error>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Your controller method

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteSport(@RequestParam("id") String id) {

    if({if id exists}) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>({your response object}, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundException("Id not found");
    }
}
```

Above `ControllerAdivce` method will get invoked, if your NotFoundException is thrown during request processing. You can always customize the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your current implementation of `SportController` will return HTTP status 200 which will never go into `error: function (e) {`. You need to throw an exception from the controller in order to get into error block.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sports-actions")
public class SportController {  

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object deleteSport(@RequestParam("id") String id) throws Error {
        throw new Error("Test exception block");
    }
}
```

Comment: But, how to combine the throw of this exception with my error class.

Comment: Your `Error` class should extend `Exception` in order to throw it as exception.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala , the return statement is never executed since you are throwing exception in previous line.

Comment: @RossiRobinsion He just wants to get into error block of javascript. It does not matter whether `return` statement gets executed or not.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala, do you get compilation error? The compiler will give you `unreachable code` error. So, it matters.

Comment: Is there a way to make custom message with my Error class instead of using the default function(string, throwable)

Comment: @RossiRobinsion Got your point. I did not think about compilation error. Thanks, I have corrected my answer.